# "Really" modification problems

Tags: meaning, adverbs, word-order

I can read a French newspaper with the aid of a dictionary, but I cannot speak the language or understand it when spoken.  So I do ***not really*** know French.

Some people say that *really* modifies *know*; others say that *not really* is a phrasal adverb that modifies the whole sentence — that is, it is not really the case that I know French.

Which of those two perspectives is correct?

Comment: _Really_ is one of a number of idiomatic expressions called [Hedges](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/lakoffhedgesCLS8.pdf) that are used, often parenthetically, to be more or less precise about degree. They are very complex and peculiar in their syntax and semantics; some of the details are in the 1972 Lakoff paper referenced in the link.

Answer (score 3):

Construct a dialogue:

> Me: You know French, don't you?
>   James: No, I don't know French.
>   Me: But you had four years of French in high school!
>   James: Yeah, but I don't REALLY know French. I just SORT OF know French.

I think that in this case, ***not*** modifies *do*, and ***really***—just like *sort of*, where the *not* distraction is removed—modifies *know*.

However:

> Me: You know French, don't you?
>   James: Not really.
>   Me: Oh, come on! I heard you say *hors de concours* not ten minutes ago.
>   James: No, really, I don't know French. Just a few phrases I picked up from novels.

In this case, ***not really*** modifies (eliptically) the assertion in my preceding utterance, and ***really*** *tout seul* modifies the following clause, including the *not* there.

Comment: Wow! As a new member, I  am impressed by the  intellectually rich answers. T

Comment: @james  Just wait til  John Lawler shows up.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, the meaning is perfectly clear from the context: ‘In spite of my modest ability in some areas of the language, my knowledge of French is far from comprehensive.’ In other words, *really* modifies the verb and nothing else. Any other interpretation is perverse.

Comment: Perverse? Really?

Comment: But "*Which* verb?" is the question OP poses.

Comment: @StoneyB: The verb in the sentence in which _really_ occurs.

Comment: Does it modify the construction *do know* or *do* or *know*?

Comment: @StoneyB: The converse is *"I **really** know French"*, so I think it's fairly obvious we're talking about whether you *know* or *really know*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Exactly. _Do_ is there only to help form the negative.

Comment: @BarrieEngland  That's my reading, too--which would not be the case with "I **do, really**, know French." So (back to OP's question), *not really* can't be taken as "a phrasal adverb that modifies the whole sentence" in this context.

Comment: @StoneyB: Quite so.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the sentence is appropriate for describing your knowledge of French. "Really" is one of those squishy adverbs that gets inserted into sentences because people like to insert phatic ("of, relating to, or being speech used for social or emotive purposes rather than for communicating information": m-w.com) remarks because they want to emphasize something that doesn't need emphasizing.

You're not pretending to know French, but you are actually managing to read French newspapers with the help of a dictionary. *I know how to read a little bit of French and am learning more every day because I read a French newspaper with a dictionary*. That's how my first father-in-law learned to read English after he arrived from Europe during WWII: *The New York Times* and a dictionary.

In some PhD programs, that's the only language requirement: a reading knowledge of works in your field. I read anthropology books in French without any trouble, but old literary ( *Les Misérables* as opposed to popular, e.g., *Le Petit Prince*) novels were beyond my comprehension. I could read the newspaper with the help of a dictionary, and I could read French subtitles in non-French films. I could speak sufficient French to call myself fluent (the words flowed without my having to search for them, and my sentences usually sounded natural, so I wasn't dismissed as a barbarian -- or thrown out of taxicabs, like some of my friends who tried to speak French in France), but my vocabulary was too small to claim more than **basic fluency** in everyday French and a few specialized topics. I did know French, but I wouldn't say that "I **really** knew French", because to me that implies being as proficient as a high school graduate (I think the average level of English proficiency in the USA is 9th grade). I wasn't **that** good at French.

A professional linguist can tell you whether "really" modifies "know" or "not really" is a phrasal adverb that modifies the whole sentence. It's not an interesting question to this amateur linguist (I think "really" modifies "know"), simply because what it does has no effect on how people understand the sentence.

That you need a dictionary to read the newspaper says all that need be said about your French reading skills and your French reading vocabulary. Really!